# Why I receive "Error parsing..." in javascript multiline string?

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets

I have xhtml file (JSF app) and I am rendering a datatable with custom column.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "/app_api/list/appsportfolio",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "scenarioName" },
            { "data": "architecture" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "contact" },
            { "data": "id", "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                    return  "<ul id=\"menu\"> \
                    <li>Actions \
                        <ul> \
                            <li class=\"ui-state-disabled\">Views</li> \
                            <li>Item 3-2</li> \
                            <li class=\"ui-state-disabled\">Actions</li> \
                            <li>Item 3-4</li> \
                            <li>Item 3-5</li> \
                        </ul>\
                    </li>\
                </ul>";
                }}
        ]
    } );

    $( "#menu" ).menu();
} );
```

Because of last custom column, I receive:

> JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing applicationPortfolioList.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 111] Open quote is expected for attribute "id" associated with an  element type  "ul".

I don't understand why it complains about quotes, isn't escaping correct?

Even if I put the entire string on the same line, the same error remains.

**UPDATE**: It seems that if I HTML encode the entire string it works fine:

`&lt;ul id=\&quot;menu\&quot;&gt;                &lt;li&gt;Actions       &lt;ul&gt;  &lt;li class=\&quot;ui-state-disabled\&quot;&gt;Views&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Item 3-2&lt;/li&gt;   &lt;li class=\&quot;ui-state-disabled\&quot;&gt;Actions&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;Item 3-4&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Item 3-5&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt;       &lt;/li&gt;             &lt;/ul&gt;`

but this is looks very ugly. If someone knows other solution please let me know.

Comment: Just put JS code in a normal JS file, not in a XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use

```
<![CDATA[ 
...
]]>
```

in your code, if you will useing '<'.
Look there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML